# Optimizing has many record association query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have this query that I've built using `Enumerable#select`. The purpose is to find records thave have no `has many` associated records or if it does have those records select only those with it's `preview` attribute set to true. The code below works perfectly for that use case. However, this query does not scale well. When I test against thousands of records it takes several hundred seconds to complete. How can this query be improved upon?

```
# User has many enrollments
# Enrollment belongs to user.

users_with_no_courses = User.includes(:enrollments).select {|user| user.enrollments.empty? || user.enrollments.where(preview: false).empty?}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first, make sure `enrollments.user_id` has an index.

Second, you can speed this up by not loading all the enrollments, and doing your filtering in SQL:

```
User.where(<<-EOQ)
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM   enrollments e
              WHERE  e.user_id = users.id
              AND    NOT e.preview)
EOQ
```

By the way here I'm simplifying your two conditions into one: "no enrollments or no real enrollments" is the same as "no real enrollments".

If you want you can put this condition into a `scope` so it is more reusable.

Third, this is still going to be slow if you're instantiating thousands of `User` objects. So I would look into paginating if that makes sense, or `find_each` if this is an offline script. Or use raw SQL to avoid all the object instances.

Oh by the way: even though you are saying `includes(:enrollments)`, this will still go back to the database, giving you an n+1 problem:

```
user.enrollments.where(preview: false)
```

That is because the `where` means ActiveRecord can't use the already-loaded association. You can avoid that by using `select` instead of `where`. But not loading the `enrollments` in the first place is even better.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for the in-depth answer!